# Dealing with ajax request in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Stackoverflow community
I have a select in my view. Onchange of which my ajax request is sent.

```html
  <%= f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@rtypes, "id", "typeName"), 
{include_blank: true },                    
{'data-rtypes': @rtypes.to_json } %>
```

.I am using Jquery ajax. My ajax works. It send an id of rtype to the show_sub_types method.

```html
$(function () {
   // specify id or class for your select tag   
   $('select').on('change', function () {
  var rtype = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "/RequestTypes/show_sub_types/"+rtype,
    type: "GET",
  })
   });
});
```

In my show_sub_types method I want to grab all subTypes (stypes) from RequestSubType model.

```html
def show_sub_types
 @rtype = params[:id];
 @stypes = RequestSubType.where("RequestType_id"==@rtype).all
         respond_to do |format|
  ... some code here
         end
 end
```

I do not know how to deal with ajax request, i dont know how to send my stypes array to the page, and how to deal with that response. I have read some tutorials, but still can not understand that respond_to part. Probably i would understand on my own example.
In my view i have div where i want to put data send by ajax (inserted into html).

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `id` of `select` and read for `data` attribute.
  Get that array in data variable, and pass it to post ajax request

```
 var data = $(this).data('rtypes');
 or
 $(this).find(':selected').data('rtypes')
 $.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url :  "/RequestTypes/show_sub_types/"+rtype,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType: "json", 
   contentType: 'application/json'
});
```